why `tcpdump -i any` can't capture unicast traffic in br0 whilst `tcpdump -i br0` can?
I am unable to capture unicast traffic on the br0 (linux bridge) interface using the command tcpdump -nni any -vvv. Broadcast traffic, however, is captured as expected. Interestingly, unicast traffic is captured if I open another terminal and run tcpdump -nni br0 -vvv to capture traffic specifically on the br0 interface simultaneously.
I've noticed that this behavior is present with tcpdump version 4.9.3 (libpcap version 1.8.1), where the tcpdump -nni any -vvv command does not capture br0 unicast traffic. However, using tcpdump version 4.99.5 (libpcap version 1.10.5 with TPACKET_V3) works correctly and captures the unicast traffic on br0.
I know that br0 get the all traffic which flow into the linux bridge device, see also Anatomy of a Linux bridge.

In cases where the destination MAC address of the incoming frame is multi- or broadcast, the bridge device is set to
receive all traffic, or the address is matches one of the local interfaces, a clone of the frame is also delivered upwards
in the local network stack by calling the br_pass_frame_
up function. The function updates the bridge device statistics, and passes the incoming frame up the network stack by
calling the device independent netif_receive_skb function

I suspect that I'm seeing may be related to the version of tcpdump or its parameters, but I can't confirm this. Could you help explain the reason for this behaviour?

According to man tcpdump:

"Note that captures on the 'any' pseudo-interface will not be done in promiscuous mode."

In practice, using the 'any' (pseudo-)interface is not equivalent to specifying a named interface as an argument.
This is because the 'any' interface will not capture traffic that is not explicitly consumed by the local machine, such as traffic passing through the interface that is not destined for it.
As a result, it may miss traffic that would otherwise be captured in promiscuous mode on a specific named interface.

Yes, I verified that if I use ‘-i br0’, it will make br0 enter the promiscuity mode to capture the traffic just in the tcpdump running time.
